# Is there difference between acne and pimples?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences

As title says: Is there difference between acne and pimples?

As far as I know "acne" is skin condition, meaning that there are number of various "pimple" types on and under the skin.

Comment: I did not downvote... but I suspect ppl will close this because you could just use a dictionary or encyclopedia for this.

Comment: Of course I looked up in dictionary, but if you do a quick search on Internet, you will realize that there are a lot of confusion :)

Comment: Ok buddy; apparently you are right. Is this useful at all? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comedo

Comment: Why not try & ask the question on [biology](http://biology.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because best asked in Biology.

Answer (score 0):

"acne" is the medical term and a modern word formation from Latin/Greek. In colloquial language people don't use Latin/Greek medical terms, they just say "pimples". It's exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

"Acne" is the medical condition.  "Pimple" is a specific instance of an inflamed spot on the skin.